# Python: pip install --pre doesn't seem to work as advertised

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

According to [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and [PEP 426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) and the [pip install manual](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) (if I read them correctly), I SHOULD be able to create pre-release versions of my libraries/wheels, and use them if-and-only-if I include the "--pre" flag.

Furthermore, I took it to mean that given the right installation options (`--pre`?) pre-release versions would fit within the standard numeric versioning scheme, such that `1.a1` and `1.dev1` would appear as `1.1`, just as `1.1+extra_tag` also appears as `1.1` (note: `+extra_tag` does not require the `--pre` flag to work)

***None of this seems to work.***

What I see is:

1. `pip install ... wheelname` installs EVEN IF the uploaded version of the wheel is something like `wheelname.1.dev6`. The `--pre` doesn't seem to make a difference, one way or the other.
2. Given a requirement file that has a stanza like `wheelname==1.6`, even with the `--pre` option, if my wheel is versioned as `wheelname.1.dev6`, `wheelname.1.a1`, etc. it is not found.
3. Same issue for a stanza like `wheelname>=1`
4. The "+notation" is honored.

It was my understanding from reading PEP 440 and 426 that the "a", "b", "c" and "cr" midfixes were supposed to be available (i.e. 1.a1 == 1.1) as long as the `--pre` option was used (of course, `--pre` isn't explicitly specified by the PEPs themselves, but I assume). Same for the ".devN" suffixes.

Notes:

- I am using pip 9.0.1
- `--isolated` does not make a difference (e.g. it is not an environment issue)
- Rather than use all the rigamarole to create a
  wheelhouse, I used a directory when creating/uploading my wheel. My approximate runlines are thus:

  `pip install wheelname --use-wheel --find-links=file:///tmp/wheelhouse [--pre]`
  `pip install -r requirements.txt --use-wheel --find-links=file:///tmp/wheelhouse  [--pre]`